# How to retrieve values from a dataset in Java

Tags: java, dataset

I have a dataset with values in two columns (x and y),

```
1974  100   
1985  150
1987  120
1999  123
```

For each x I want to get the value of y. How do I do this in Java? I have an idea on where to start, but not how to continue. I have created a dynamical parameter called *data* of type Dataset, and since the x column is year I was thinking about doing something like this;

```
data().get( getYear() + getDayOfYear(date())/365 )
```

Is this a correct way of thinking or am I totally on the wrong track? Also if I wasn't using java.util.Date how would I get the value of y for each x?

Comment: it what type is your data? array? object?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a dataset that maps each year to, say, the number of times something happened in that year. If your data set contains exactly one y for any given year (i.e. you do not have two rows for 1986) then what you want is a Map from the java.util.Collection framework. Something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> dataset = new HashMap<>();  // my syntax assumes you have java7+
dataset.add(1974,100);
dataset.add(1985,150);
…
```

to retrieve the data for a particular year, use

```
int numberOfEvents = dataset.get(theYear);
```

here are a couple of good references to point you on your way:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/
- http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/using_4.shtml

Since you asked, here's how you would load this from a text file:

```
public class DataSetLoader {
   public static void main(String []args){
      Map<Integer,Integer> myData = loadData("/path/to/my/data.txt");
   }

   // load the dataset; may return an empty or partly filled map if there is an error
   private static Map<Integer,Integer> loadData(String filename) {
      Map<Integer,Integer> dataset = new HashMap<>();
      try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
         String s;
         while ((s = r.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = s.split("\\s+");
            Integer year = Integer.valueOf(columns[0]);
            Integer data = Integer.valueOf(columns[1]);
            System.out.println("Adding ("+year+","+data+")");
            dataset.put(year,data);
         }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         // this is not great exception handling, but it will let you know about 
         // any problems while debugging
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      return dataset;
   }  

}
```

If your data is not clean, the `Integer.valueOf()` may throw a NumberFormatException, too - you may want to catch that explicitly. Eventually, you want to remove the catch-all exception handling, and replace with catch clauses for `FileNotFoundException`, `IOException`, and maybe `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, but the dataset output above is much longer than those 4 rows. Doing *dataset.add* will take forever. Is there another way one can possibly loop through it?

Comment: @user2481390 Yes, of course; you can make a loop and add the data in the loop, but your original question didn't say where your data set was coming from (is it coming from a text file? a database query? are the values calculated via some expensive calculation you don't want to repeat? etc.) I will update my answer to illustrate loading from a text file.

Comment: Can I also use HashMap if I dynamically want to get a value from the dataset? When I run the code I wanted to create some animation text shape that "prints" out one x value at a time. Right now I seem to go through the entire dataset and only "printing" out the last value (1999).

Answer (score 0):

use a HashMap... you can put the name:value pair into the map and retrieve via the name

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put(name,value);

String retValue =map.get(name);
```

Date could be your value.